# Install RSAT-Hyper-V-tools fails on Windows Server 2012 R2 Server Core

Tags: virtualization, powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-core

When I try to install Rsat-Hyper-v-tools with powershell command:
add-windowsfeature rsat-hyper-v-tools -includeAllSubFeature

It fails with error saying that:

```
The source files could not be downloaded. Error: 0x800F0906
```

Also :

```
CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (@(Vhd=; Credent...Name=Localhost):PSObject) ..
FullyQualifiedErrorId: DISMAPI_Error__Cbs_Download_Failure
```

I have tried googling issue without success. Might be something to do with Windows updates or not.

Im running hyper-v on this PC and cannot install tools to control VMS. Is there other way to start VM's in case I can't use another PC to start them? For example I am running Domain controller on this VM host, and if it goes down, I can't start it from another PC because of no access rights(DC down). Or can i use PS remote command with that local pc administrator account?

Comment: The "R" stands for "remote", right? Isn't the RSAT meant to be installed on Windows 8 for the purposes of managing a server (core or full) from a workstation?

Comment: Might be, yet RSAT is still lot easier to install on Windows Server (full) than on workstation. Personally I use Windows Servers to manage other Windows Servers. Thou I use mac and remote desktop + use direct console access when needed. Very low amount of Win 8's in our company and can't install hyper-v manager on windows 7, which could control windows 2012 R2 server. Thus most of my work is done through VMHost which is running window server 2012 R2 (full).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey went to look in to one russian forum(i think) and there was english command:

Add-windowsfeature hyper-v-powershell

Which successfully installed powershell cmdlets (phew).

Comment: Glad you've resolved this. Please be sure to [mark your answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able.